# Data from imported json file doesn't load if web page opened on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, json

Revised and simplified version of previous question:

Project published on a github with live preview page.
In project folder I have 3 files - index.html, data.json and script.js

In index.html body

```
<h1 class="heading"></h1>
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
```

In data.json

```
[
  {
    "day": "mon",
    "amount": 17.45
  },
  {
    "day": "tue",
    "amount": 34.91
  },
  {
    "day": "wed",
    "amount": 52.36
  },
  {
    "day": "thu",
    "amount": 31.07
  },
  {
    "day": "fri",
    "amount": 23.39
  },
  {
    "day": "sat",
    "amount": 43.28
  },
  {
    "day": "sun",
    "amount": 25.48
  }
]
```

In script.js

```
import data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };
const heading = document.querySelector(".heading");

heading.textContent = data[0].day;
```

Problem:

If I open live preview page on desktop PC heading text content is "mon", but if I open it on mobile, .heading is empty.

Question:

Why data from json file didn't load on mobile using import?

Live preview available here:

https://lafistik.github.io/letmetestthis/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).